# Can't get shared-styles to work in Polymer when in different folder

Tags: css, polymer, polymer-1.0

I need to share the same CSS with all of my Polymer components. From what I've searched, placing the link with the stylesheet directly is deprecated, so is *core-style*.

So I tried to use what I believe is called style module. In a separate file, named shared-styles.html, I've inserted the CSS I wanted and then I import it through `<style is="custom-style" include="shared-styles"></style>`.

This works when shared-styles is in the same folder as my element/component, but it wouldn't be very practical to copy and paste the CSS again and again in all the folders, so I wanted to keep the styles in its own folder. However, the styles disappear when I do that.

The importing path seems correct to me, but either way I tried to change it and nothing happens.

I've tried many other things such as adding or removing "async" from the link tag, adding or removing is=custom-style from the style tag, but no change so far.

**One idea I had is, maybe the problem is how I'm testing my components, since *polymer server --open* only gets the files that are in the component folder.**

[Here's a pen, but you can't really see the problem there, since I can't put the CSS in a different folder.](https://codepen.io/andreaweb/pen/VbvVvG)

Any guidance would be deeply appreciated.

Console errors:

```
127.0.0.1/:1 GET http://127.0.0.1:8081/shared-styles/shared-styles.html 404 (Not Found)
polymer.html:2654 Could not find style data in module named shared-styles
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right guys, sorry if my question was confusing.

**The issue was indeed related to *polymer server --open* only getting the files that are in the component folder**, therefore ignoring the styles in a different folder.

The way **I fixed it** was **by creating a shortcut** to the outside folder inside the component folder, and then just normally inserting the style like this:

```
<link rel="import" href="shared-styles/shared-styles.html">
```

Hope it helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are not defining the `dom-module` id for your `shared-styles`.

The correct `shared-styles/shared-styles.html` file should be:

```
<dom-module id="shared-styles">
   <template>
       <style>
          /** your CSS goes here **/
       </style>
   </template>
</dom-module>
```

Comment: I did define, as I said the codePen doesn't really show the problem, since you can't see more than one html or folder there. But co-workers have agreed the problem is that the server can't find a folder outside its "scope". We're gonna test using a shortcut for the folder and if it works I'll post later.